# Smallest field cotaining 1/3

Tags: abstract-algebra

What is the smallest subfield $F$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $1/3 \in F$?

I think that $F=\mathbb{Q}$, because if $1/3 \in F$, then $1/3+1/3+1/3=1 \in F$ and then $\mathbb{Z} \subset F$, therefore for any $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ we have $n/3^m \in F$. Thus, any sum the fractions of form $n/3^m$ belong $F$.As we can write any rational number in basis $3$, follows that $F \subset \mathbb{Q}$ and it is obvius that $\mathbb{Q} \subset F$, thus $F=\mathbb{Q}$.

Correct or no?
Thanks!

Comment: The prime field is $\mathbb{Q}$, and $1/3$ is rational. So yes, you are right.

Comment: Correct. $\mathbb Q$ is the prime field of $\mathbb R$ (smallest subfield) and contains $\frac13$. That's enough.

Comment: "we can write any rational number in basis $3$": yes, but in general the base-$3$ expansion will be infinite. So you can't use that fact here.

Comment: @TonyK You can write all positive *integers* as finite sums of 3 powers.

Comment: @Henno: Yes, but cgomesmat wrote "any rational number".

Comment: @csgomesmat It is not necessary to prove $\mathbb Z\subset F$ on base of $\frac13\in F$. The fact that $F$ is a field allready tells us that $1\in F$, consequently $\mathbb Z\subset F$ and finally $\mathbb Q\subseteq F$.